# How can one implement a forking try-catch in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, try-catch, fork

I want to write a function

```
forkos_try :: IO (Maybe α) -> IO (Maybe α)
```

which Takes a command `x`. `x` is an imperative operation which first mutates state, and then checks whether that state is messed up or not. *(It does not do anything external, which would require some kind of OS-level sandboxing to revert the state.)*

- if `x` evaluates to `Just y`, `forkos_try` returns `Just y`.
- otherwise, `forkos_try` *rolls back state*, and returns `Nothing`.

Internally, it should `fork()` into threads `parent` and `child`, with `x` running on `child`.

- if `x` succeeds, `child` should keep running (returning `x`'s result) and `parent` should die
- otherwise, `parent` should keep running (returning `Nothing`) and `child` should die

*Question*: What's the way to write something with equivalent, or more powerful semantics than `forkos_try`? **N.B. -- the state mutated** (by `x`) **is in an external library, and cannot be passed between threads**. Hence, the semantic of which thread to keep alive is important.

Formally, "keep running" means "execute some continuation `rest :: Maybe α -> IO ()` ". But, that continuation isn't kept anywhere explicit in code.

For my case, I think it will (for the time) work to write it in different style, using `forkOS` (which takes the entire computation `child` will run), since I can write an explicit expression for `rest`. But, it troubles me that I can't figure out how do this with the primitive function `forkOS` -- one would think it would be general enough to support any specific case (which could appear as a high-level API, like `forkos_try`).

**EDIT** -- please see the example code with explicit `rest` if the problem's still not clear [ http://pastebin.com/nJ1NNdda ].

p.s. I haven't written concurrency code in a while; hopefully my knowledge of POSIX `fork()` is correct! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a novice implementation taking an explicit continuation: http://pastebin.com/nJ1NNdda

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  The state appears to be in the IO monad, but you want to roll it back - since that can't be done in general (e.g. maybe you launched some missiles), how is the state to be rolled back?

Comment: I think the OP wants to use OS-level fork (i.e., not `forkIO`).  That would allow you to roll back all internal state like `IORef`s.  Of course, it can't roll back things written into files.

Comment: @gatoatigrado Your solution would be very heavyweight if it uses forkOS (e.g., the child process would have to start up a new IO manager and other runtime services). Since you only want to mutate state, have you considered using the `ST` monad?  That allows you to have state, but does not require you to be in IO.

Comment: @SimonMarlow, the "roll back" is only in concept. The actual semantics is that the parent thread, which hasn't executed `x`, does the rest of computation.

Comment: Note: `forkOS` is not `fork()`. Perhaps you meant [`forkProcess`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/unix/System-Posix-Process.html#v:forkProcess)?

Answer (score 2):

Things are a lot simpler to reason about if you model state explicitly.

```
someStateFunc :: (s -> Maybe (a, s))

-- inside some other function
case someStateFunc initialState of
  Nothing -> ... -- it failed. stick with initial state
  Just (a, newState) -> ... -- it suceeded. do something with
                            -- the result and new state
```

With immutable state, "rolling back" is simple: just keep using `initialState`. And "not rolling back" is also simple: just use `newState`.

So...I'm assuming from your explanation that this "external library" performs some nontrivial IO effects that are nevertheless restricted to a few knowable and reversible operations (modify a file, an IORef, etc). There is no way to reverse some things (launch the missiles, write to stdout, etc), so I see one of two choices for you here:

1. clone the world, and run the action in a sandbox. If it succeeds, then go ahead and run the action in the Real World.
2. clone the world, and run the action in the real world. If it fails, then replace the Real World with the snapshot you took earlier.

Of course, both of these are actually the same approach: fork the world. One world runs the action, one world doesn't. If the action succeeds, then that world continues; otherwise, the other world continues. You are proposing to accomplish this by building upon `forkOS`, which would clone the entire state of the program, but this would not be sufficient to deal with, for example, file modifications. Allow me to suggest instead an approach that is nearer to the simplicity of immutable state:

```
tryIO :: IO s -> (s -> IO ()) -> IO (Maybe a) -> IO (Maybe a)
tryIO save restore action = do
  initialState <- save
  result <- action
  case result of
    Nothing -> restore initialState >> return Nothing
    Just x  -> return (Just x)
```

Here you must provide some data structure `s`, and a way to `save` to and `restore` from said data structure. This allows you the flexibility to perform any cloning you know to be necessary. (e.g. `save` could copy a certain file to a temporary location, and then `restore` could copy it back and delete the temporary file. Or `save` could copy the value of certain IORefs, and then `restore` could put the value back.) This approach may not be the most efficient, but it's very straightforward.

Comment: Sorry, I said in bold text that `s` can't be passed between threads; in particular, it can't be turned into a Haskell type either. It's some state that exists in a C library.

Comment: Note: `forkOS` just starts a thread, like `forkIO`, but bound to a new OS-level thread. To fork the process, you want [`System.Posix.forkProcess`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/unix/System-Posix-Process.html#v:forkProcess).

Comment: @gatoatigrado the solution I suggest is singly-threaded, so that isn't an issue. But you have no way to snapshot this state? If you want to be able to roll it back, that will prove quite problematic. Having no recourse other than resorting to a process fork is a very strong code smell.

Comment: @DanBurton, Yes, resorting to a process fork is inoptimal. But, I'm not going to rewrite hundreds of thousands of lines of C code so that I can serialize or functionalize certain parts of it. Thanks anyway though.